# How Does a Cached Thread Pool Reuse Existing Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I've just started looking at Java's `Executors` class and the `newCachedThreadPool( )` method. According to the API, the resulting thread pool reuses existing `Thread` objects for new tasks.

I'm a bit puzzled how this is implemented because I couldn't find any method in the `Thread` API that lets you set the behaviour of an existing `Thread` object.

For example, you can create a *new* `Thread` from a `Runnable` object, which makes the `Thread` call the `Runnable`'s `run( )` method. However, there is no setter method in the `Thread` API that takes a `Runnable` as an argument.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The answer IOW:  a `Thread` performs almost the same task (or should I say subset of tasks) as the combination of `Runnable` and `ExecutorService` with the exception that the latter combo gives you more features to take advantage of.  So much so that you should *really* be considering why you are using a `Thread` alone if doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executors does everything for you in the background. And yes it uses the existing thread API only.

Below link has sample implementation of Thread pool implemented using Thread class and Collection API: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html

Comment: For some reason my first comment wasn't posted. Thanks for clarifying.  When I posted the question I wrongly assumed the threads had no knowledge of the thread pool's internals.

Answer (score 28):

Basically imagine each thread from the pool doing this:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if(tasks available) {
           Runnable task = taskqueue.dequeue();
           task.run();
        } else {
           // wait or whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The threadpool has threads that look for runnable jobs. Instead of starting a new thread from the `Runnable` the thread will just call the function `run()`. So a thread in a `ThreadPool` isn't created with the `Runnable` you provide,but with one that just checks if any tasks are ready to be executed and calls them directly.

So it would look something like this:

```
while(needsToKeepRunning()){
    if(hasMoreTasks()){
        getFirstTask().run();.
    }
    else
    {
        waitForOtherTasks();
    }
}
```

Of course this is overly simplified the real implementation with the waiting is much more elegant. A great source of information on how this really works can be found in [Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

Comment: Thanks. Got it. (And thanks to all others who answered my question.)

Answer (score 4):

Threads are created **only once** in the Thread Pool API (except in the cases when due to some exception the thread exits abruptly)

The Worker threads poll the **Queue** to see if there is a task and use it. So the threads never exit.

It is just an abstraction that Threads are reused (Abstraction for they never actually stop). Obviously they stop after idle timeout and shutdown request.

**Runnable -----> Thread Pools** (Some worker thread consumes that Runnable and others wait for some more Runnables)

Answer (score 2):

Well the thread only have to call `Runnable.run()` on the runnables which are assigned to him...

Answer (score 2):

A simplified explanation is that when you pass a Runnable to the ExecutorService the Runnable is put into a queue. The ThreadPool worker threads reads from this queue and invokes the queued Runnables run() method.

Comment: Thanks. When I posted the question I was assuming the `Thread`s had no knowledge of the implementation of the thread pool.