# Does thread used in @Scheduled annotation released to pool before finishing execution?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, java-threads, spring-scheduled

I have 5 @Scheduled annotated methods and pool size of my ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is 10. Annotations of my methods are the same and like this.

> @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 10000)

My question is that;

When one of the scheduled methods gets a thread from pool and start to run; does it release the thread to pool before its execution is finished? (for example in case of context switch etc.) or this thread is used until the end of the execution?

I mean is it possible to some part of the scheduled task is done with thread-1 and some part is done with thread-2 ?

Comment: Do you mean pool or poll? Looks like there might be a typo

Comment: You will have to create another thread yourself when the scheduled method is triggered if you want part of that method to be executed in another thread.

Comment: @AlexW yes it was a typo. Thx.

Comment: @Rakesh actually I don't want to split execution to different thread. I just want to know default behavior of spring scheduler.

Answer (score 4):

Threading is complicated and my understanding is not as great as others, but here's my attempt at a brief explanation of how the `@Scheduled` Spring annotation works:

Spring uses a `TaskScheduler`:

```
public interface TaskScheduler {

    ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger);

    ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Date startTime, long delay);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay);

}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler

Which submits the annotated code, i.e. task code, to a high-level concurrency object called an executor.  The executor class is `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.  That class submits tasks to the thread pool to be run by the first available thread in the pool.  The thread pool size you set determines how many active threads you can have. If you set `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` to `true` then threads in the pool that have no work available to do within their timeout interval will be terminated.

Spring uses a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to manage the thread pool:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java

Keeping a pool of threads alive reduces the time that would normally be added while waiting for the thread to be created. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765904/how-threadpool-re-use-threads-and-how-it-works) for some more info.

Ultimately, the `java.lang.Thread` class runs the Runnable or Callable instances that are created by the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.  The `Thread` class implements a `run()` method that is basically your code you want the thread to run:

```
public Thread(Runnable target) {
    init(null, target, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}

private void init(ThreadGroup g, Runnable target, String name,
                  long stackSize, AccessControlContext acc) {
...
```

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java

The actual switching between threads, i.e. the context switch [is OS-dependent](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores) but in general threads will be divided amongst CPUs and then each CPU cycles through the threads based on the timeout interval and does a bit of work and then pauses and switches continuously between threads until the task(s) are complete.

> does it release the thread to pool before its execution is finished?
>   (for example in case of context switch etc.) or this thread is used
>   until the end of the execution?

The Runnable code can definitely stop executing in the middle of an operation but the Threads in a thread pool are usually kept alive until there's no more work to be done.

Here's more info from the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) that explains thread pools:

> Most of the executor implementations in java.util.concurrent use
>   thread pools, which consist of worker threads. This kind of thread
>   exists separately from the Runnable and Callable tasks it executes and
>   is often used to execute multiple tasks.
>
> Using worker threads minimizes the overhead due to thread creation.
>   Thread objects use a significant amount of memory, and in a
>   large-scale application, allocating and deallocating many thread
>   objects creates a significant memory management overhead.
>
> One common type of thread pool is the fixed thread pool. This type of
>   pool always has a specified number of threads running; if a thread is
>   somehow terminated while it is still in use, it is automatically
>   replaced with a new thread. Tasks are submitted to the pool via an
>   internal queue, which holds extra tasks whenever there are more active
>   tasks than threads.
>
> An important advantage of the fixed thread pool is that applications
>   using it degrade gracefully. To understand this, consider a web server
>   application where each HTTP request is handled by a separate thread.
>   If the application simply creates a new thread for every new HTTP
>   request, and the system receives more requests than it can handle
>   immediately, the application will suddenly stop responding to all
>   requests when the overhead of all those threads exceed the capacity of
>   the system. With a limit on the number of the threads that can be
>   created, the application will not be servicing HTTP requests as
>   quickly as they come in, but it will be servicing them as quickly as
>   the system can sustain.

Comment: thanks for this comprehensive explanation. But I guess Spring's Scheduled annotation must have a design decision about this. (like a thread is not released until end of execution or can be released etc.) But unfortunately I cannot find it in spring documentation. Because I want to use a thread scoped spring bean in scheduled job but I want to be sure if it is safe to use it. (if thread is released then the data could be mixed with another thread's data etc.) Do you have any information about it? Is it safe to use thread scope bean in a Scheduled method?

Comment: @H.Ç.T As far as I know, Spring doesn't take responsibility for thread safety.  So, you'll have to use the normal Java methods for ensuring thread safety, e.g. `volatile` variables to share state, `synchronized` blocks to guarantee exclusivity of operations, etc. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702386/is-executorservice-specifically-threadpoolexecutor-thread-safe#answer-7596354) has some info also.

Comment: Also, it's dependent on the task for whether or not it's thread-safe.  If the threads are modifying a file, you'll definitely have to manage state between them.  If all of the threads store their info in local memory and can do the operations concurrently without stepping on each other then there's nothing to worry about.