# Threadpool re-use of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I know this topic has been asked a lot, but im not sure about one detail.
Now threadpool doesnt let a thread die after completing a task, and reuses it later on as needed (as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699335/how-does-a-cached-thread-pool-reuse-existing-threads), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765904/how-threadpool-re-use-threads-and-how-it-works), etc) 
But let say my runnable has variables in the constuctor -

```
MyRunnable(int a){
  this.a = a; 
}
```

then, when we try to run the Runnable with a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` (or something similar), we say

```
executor.execute(new MyRunnable(a)); // executor being Executors.newFixedThreadPool
```

now if variable 'a' is different in every execute, can Threadpool really reuse it later? 
I cant really understand how that would work, but i never seen 'Threadpool reuses threads except...', hence the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, neither the `Runnable` you submit, nor the variables related to it, will be reused.

I think you mis-understood `Thread` and `Runnable`, they are different things. A `Runnable` is just normal object, execept its `run` method will be executed when you create a new thread with it. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run).

The re-use of thread does not mean the re-use of `Runnable`, it means the thread keeps executing different `Runnable`s.

---

When you create a `Thread` with a `Runnable`, and `start` this thread like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()).start()
```

the `run()` method of this `Runnale` will be executed, and after the `run()` exiting, this `Thread` will terminate too.

But, the `Runnbale` you submit to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is not the one in code above to construct the thread.

---

Briefly, threads in `ThreadPoolExecutor` are created like this:

```
Runnable worker = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Runnable firstTask = getFirstTask();  // the first runnable 
        firstTask.run();

        Runnable queuedTask;
        while ( (queuedTask = getTaskFromQueue()) != null) {  // This could get blocked 
            queuedTask.run();
        }
    }
};
new Thread(worker).start();
```

Note, the `Runnable` used to initate the thread is not the one you submitted to the pool.

---

When you submit new `Runnable`, the thread pool will check if it need to create new thread(based on the argument like `corePoolSize`).

- If it is necessary, then it create a new `Worker` with this `Runnable` as `FirstTask`, and create a new thread with this `Worker` and start it.
- If not, then it put the `Runnbale` in a queue. When there are free threads, they will check this queue and take tasks from it.

Answer (score 2):

So, from my point how the thread pool working algorithm would be similar  and looks like below

```
while (check if the pool is not shutdown) {
    Runnable task = pool.fetchTaskFromQueue(); // fetch the Task from the queue. In your case it object of MyRunnable class
    task.run(); // call the run() of MyRunnable object
}
```

Thread pool resues the `Thread`, not the `Runnable/ Callable` implementation. So, as per thread pool, it does reuse your `variable a`.